# Can bool(datetime) evaluate to False in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8

If you have a `value: Optional[X]`, a common way to check if it is `None` is by by using the pattern:

```py
from typing import Optional

def some_function(value: Optional[str]):
    if not value:
        print("oopsie! value is either None or the empty string")
        return
    ...  # now you know that value is not empty
```

The gotcha with this pattern is other values that evaluate to `False`, e.g.:

- `X == str`: `""`
- `X == int`: `0`
- `X == float`: `0.0` ... interestingly, `bool(float('nan')) is True`
- `X == list`: `[]` (similar for sets, tuples, dicts, or other iterables)

My question is: Does any `datetime.datetime` object evaluate to `False`? Any `datetime.time` / `datetime.date`?

Comment: More accurately, each of the values you list evaluate as "falsy", not `None`. `None` is also "falsy". See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983695/what-is-truthy-and-falsy-how-is-it-different-from-true-and-false for an explanation.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Thank you, that was a typo. I fixed it in the question :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Checking [the source code for `datetime`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/datetime.py), we see that it does not override `__bool__()`. Therefore the only "falsey" value for a variable with type `Optional[datetime]` object is `None`.

Comment: Nice! Thank you for also pointing me to the source! I'll accept in 7 minutes (as soon as I can :-) )

Comment: You've linked to the Python implementation, but most of that gets overwritten by `from _datetime import *` near the end. The implementation that matters for most cases is the C implementation, [which also doesn't override `__bool__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.9.2/Modules/_datetimemodule.c#L6431).

Comment: (A timedelta *can* be falsy, though.)

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Thanks for the link to the C source. I didn't consider that since I found the Python code.

Comment: Those classes also do not define `__len__` - https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__bool__.